# SQL Server Doesn't Find Record Containing Float Value That It Returned

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, rounding-error

I have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT SpecimenID, TestPeriodID, Grams, ConsumptionRate FROM LabData
WHERE TestPeriodID = 255 
AND TestID = 1 
AND Grams = 728560
```

The record that is returned has a value of 16.5667068820687 for the FLOAT column ConsumptionRate.

I now add the following to the end of my query:

```
AND ConsumptionRate = 16.5667068820687
```

Executing the new query returns zero records, even though the additional criteria are exactly what SQL Server itself reported.  I assume that this is a rounding error.  However, I have a CLR function that is executing the 2nd query based on the results returned by the first.

What can I do to in my generated search criteria to maintain an accurate representation of the first result, but not miss existing records in the second result?

Comment: What is the data type of ConsumptionRate? `EXECUTE sys.describe_first_result_set N'SELECT ConsumptionRate FROM LabData AS L'`

Comment: I'm guessing one is being interpreted as a DECIMAL. `DECLARE @x FLOAT = 16.5667068820687; SELECT @x WHERE @x = CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,12),16.5667068820687);` Why are you using FLOAT (which has known and documented rounding issues?

Comment: Also, why are you identifying a row by the value instead of by the ID columns? This is like identifying an Employee by name or DateHired instead of by SSN or EmployeeID - what happens when you hired two John Smiths? On the same day?

Comment: @AaronBertrand One must die, obviously. [Thunderdome](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmRAiUPdRjk)?

Comment: @ billinkc - The type is FLOAT, per my question title.

Comment: @BuggieBoy and what is the parameter's type?

Comment: You should never compare floats with equality in that manner. If you must use float use `BETWEEN` with an epsilon value.

Comment: I'm down to my last finger for typing having been bit by far too many questions that specify one thing but really *meant* the other and thus, the verification. ;)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'm not identifying any row by a value, this is a constructed example.  As for the use of FLOAT, it is an existing database, the design of which I have no control over.

Comment: And does it work when you explicitly convert: `ConsumptionRate = CONVERT(FLOAT, 16.566...)`? And yes, you are identifying a row by a value when you add an explicit check in the where clause for a specific value in a specific column. (And just because the title of the question says `float` is no guarantee that's the actual data type. It might also be useful to know what precision is used - `FLOAT(5)` is not the same as `FLOAT(53)`.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Good question.  I just tried ConsumptionRate = CONVERT(FLOAT, 16.566...).  Still doesn't return the row.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Probably the value stored is not exactly `16.5667068820687` so it will never work. e.g. `DECLARE @T TABLE(F FLOAT);INSERT INTO @T VALUES (16.56670688206871);SELECT * FROM @T; /*Returns 16.5667068820687*/ SELECT * FROM @T WHERE F = 16.5667068820687 /*Returns Nothing*/`

Comment: @MartinSmith right, going back to my questioning the use of FLOAT in the first place, and bothering to perform a comparison using that column to (help) identify a row.

Comment: @Buggieboy What kind of range are you looking at for this column and how close is the value to other samples in the population?  You might be able to use BETWEEN on one of the latter decimal places to capture the value you are looking for

Comment: Use this `AND CAST(ConsumptionRate as numeric(18,2)) = '16.56'`

Comment: Ugh... @Justin I don't think that's a good idea at all, for a variety of reasons

Comment: I bet `AND CAST(ConsumptionRate AS int) = 16` would find the row too /facepalm

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Column properties show the numeric precision to be 53.

Comment: @AaronBertrand and bilinkc yeh, I just wanna say that him need to find desirable precision, maybe 18,6 or 18,8, but again float is not numeric and precisly sometimes canot be found. I had one case where float was number 1/3 (1 divided by 3)

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use - does it bring any result?

```
ConsumptionRate > 16.56 AND ConsumptionRate < 16.57
```